# Breaking down textfile into Arraylist - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to break down a data text file which is in the format of:

```
kick, me, 10
kick, you, 20
```

into `arrayList<customlist> = new arrayList`

```
class customlist
{
  string something, string something2, int times
}
```

So my question is how can I get each part of the text file data to each part of the customlist.

eg: kick -> something, me -> something2 and 10 -> times

Comment: What have you tried? Please show actual compiling code (unless getting it to compile is the problem) - and describe where/what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, from your post I cannot tell where your problem lies precisely, so I don’t know how to guide you. Instead, tell us what search and research you have done, and edit the question to include your best attempt and how it fails or is insufficient. We can much better guide you from there. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My advice: use XML or JSON for structured text. It makes read/write operations much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split each line into its components using `String.split(",")`.
Apply `String.trim()` to each member in order to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: He wants to create POJO from Text File. Only splitting the String will lead him nowhere

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to solve this type of problem, here you can simply read all text from that text file by using InputStream and BufferReader after geting all text you can do somthing like:-

```
  ArrayList<CustomList> getArrayList(String textFileData)
{
    ArrayList<CustomList> customLists = new ArrayList<>() ;
    String data[] = textFileData.split(",");

    int i = data.length;

    int position = 0;
    while (position<i)
    {
        String somthing = data[position];
        String somthing1 = data[position+1];
        String temp = data[position+2].split(" ")[0];
        int times = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        CustomList customList= new CustomList();
        customList.setSomething(somthing);
        customList.setSomething2(somthing1);
        customList.setTimes(times);
        customLists.add(customList);
        position = position+3;

    }

    return customLists;

}
```

Note: this is refer if you are using same string pattern as you mention in the above problem

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Scanner` object to read the lines and breaking up each line using the `split()` function. Then, create a new `customlist` object, and add it into your `ArrayList<customlist>`.

```
public void readFile(File file, ArrayList<customlist> myList)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String line;
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
       line=sc.nextLine();
       String[] fields = line.split(",");
       int times = Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim());
       customlist myCustom = new myList(fields[0].trim(), fields[1].trim(), 
       times);
       myList.add(myCustom);
     }
    sc.close();
}
```

You may also handle exceptions if you think its necessary.